# Formulário com loop de ano fabricação

Tags: php, javascript, html, formulário

Boa tarde!
Estou desenvolvendo um formulário para cadastro de carros, onde eu vou informar o ano de fabricação e ano que parou de fabricar. Estou puxando os dado uma tabela para selecionar o ano de fabricação, e para o ano final estou recuperando o valor com o seguinte código:

```
 <script>
   $('#ano').change(function(e) {
   var texto = document.getElementById('ano').value;
   document.getElementById('ano2').value = texto;
   })
 </script>
```

Preciso pegar esse valor e somar até que seja o ano final do veiculo e fazer esse valor aparecer no meu select do formulário.

```
                       <div class="field"> 
                            <label class="label">Ano do Veículo Final</label>
                            <div class="select is-fullwidth">
                                <div class="field">
                                    <select name="ano2" id='ano2'> 
                                       
                                    </select>       
                                </div>
                            </div>                                    
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Passe o valor da variável `texto` para uma função que vai popular o select `ano2`

Na função que vai popular, realize um loop `do .. while` que vai adicionar os options

```js
       var anoFabricado=2010; // puxado de uma tabela 
       
    $('#ano').change(function(e) {
       // passe esse valor para uma função que vai popular o select ano2
       var texto = document.getElementById('ano').value;
       //opcional
       document.getElementById("ano2").innerHTML = '<option value="" disabled selected>Ano fabricação até Final</option>';
       popularSelect(texto);
    })
       
     function popularSelect(anoFinal){

        //elemento a ser populado
        var meuSelect = document.getElementById("ano2");
  
        var LeandroDias = function(max){
        
            do{
              meuSelect.add(new Option(anoFabricado++,max--),null);
            }while(max>=0);
            
         }(anoFinal-anoFabricado);
    };
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                               
    <select name="ano" id='ano'> 
      <option>2011
      <option>2012
      <option>2013
      <option>2014
      <option>2015
      <option>2016
      <option>2017
      <option>2018
      <option>2019
      <option>2020
    </select>

    <select name="ano2" id='ano2'> 
    </select>
```